# Session cookie restricted by path?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, session-cookies

My question is: is a session cookie restricted by path on a site? That is, if a cookie is set in **mysite.net/rodents/gerbil/** does it not apply to another path such as **mysite.net/rodents/hamster**?

The context is:

I've developed a simple site at http://sonet.nottingham.ac.uk/rlos/placs/users_carers/home in which I want to use a cookie to allow page narration to autostart, or not, as the user enters a page. By default autostart is off, but if the user ticks the checkbox by the audio player at the top and goes to another page, the cookie `autoplay` is set to `on` and the player `autostart` parameter is set to `true` in the PHP (CodeIgniter).

This works fine in a site section (eg Home) but when the user moves to another section (eg Next Steps) the cookie disappears, according to Firebug. So if I tick the checkbox in Home then FB reports the cookie:

- name: autoplay
- value: on
- domain: sonet.nottingham.ac.uk
- size: 10 B
- path: /rlos/placs/users_carers/
- expires: Session

If I go to another page in Home the cookie remains. If I go to [Next Steps](http://sonet.nottingham.ac.uk/rlos/placs/users_carers/steps/whatnext) the cookie disappears, though if I tick the checkbox FB reports the cookie as set but with the path '/rlos/placs/users_carers/steps/'. Interestingly, switching amongst sections and checking the box generates a cookie per path.

I've not really used cookies in my sites up to now, preferring PHP session variables, but I'd thought that setting a session cookie was simple and for reasons I'll not bore folk with I wanted the cookie set clientside using jQuery. I could solve this problem by setting a persistent cookie, but a) I don't want to leave a cookie on the user's machine, and b) I want to know what the flip is going on.

It may be that I've not gone the best way about this, but this project has to be finished by Tuesday so there's no way I can redo my approach.

Comment: Er, well the query is about cookies. Whether I'm using Codeigniter or Hamsterscript as a back end, or jQuery or Beaverware clientside isn't relevant. But wtf, I'll add some more tags as I like keeping folk happy. The simple question is: are session cookies path-restricted?

Comment: No, they are not (at least in CI), all depends in how you set the cookie settings in the config file. For example, putting `/` as path you are allowed to play with it around your entire side. Is this what you are tacking about?

Comment: The cookie is un/set using jQuery, with the jquery.cookie plugin (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). I'm only reading the cookie in CI. Maybe it's the plugin that's causing the problem - I'll investigate. I was too het up with the thing last night to think clearly :(

Answer (score 0):

That's what the [session.cookie_path](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path) directive determines:

> **session.cookie_path** `string`
>       `session.cookie_path` specifies path to set in the session cookie. **Defaults to /.** See also [session_get_cookie_params()](http://php.net/session_get_cookie_params) and
>   [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params)().

However, your cookie is called `autoplay` and has a value of `on`, thus it's *not* a session cookie (which is called `PHPSESSID` by default and contains a long random string). Regular cookies are created with [set_cookie()](http://php.net/set_cookie):

> bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [,
>   **string $path** [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )

... where:

> **path**
>  The path on the server in which the cookie will be
>   available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the
>   entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available
>   within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/
>   of domain. **The default value is the current directory that the cookie
>   is being set in**.

To sum up: you need to set path explicitly.

**Edit:** I hadn't noticed the jQuery tag. Quoting your plug-ins docs:

> Create expiring cookie, valid across entire site:
>
> `$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });`